# How to prove this trig inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the following inequality with $d=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}$
$$2r^2t(1-\cos{2\theta})+4a^2t-\frac{\sin{4dt}}{2d}[(d^2+a^2)\cos{2\theta}-r^2]-a(1-\cos{4dt})\sin{2\theta}>0$$
where all variables are real, $t>0,r>0$ and $a\neq0$. In the setting, $a$ is some constant while time $t$ can grow and it is in the 2D plane $r(\cos{\theta},\sin{\theta})$. In the original problem, we have a 2D function $f(r,\theta)$ and we want to prove $\partial_rf$, given above, has a definite sign. Since this is already self-contained, I feel probably digressing to show $f$.

The first two terms linear in $t$, which are positive, presumably dominates when $t$ is large enough. But I notice from very extended numerics that it actually holds in general. So can we prove it in general? Or something simpler: estimating a *lower bound* $t_c$, which *only* depends on $a$, to guarantee its positivity.

Comment: I think using some formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ may help, see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Trigonometrie). E.g. I see two products $\sin 4dt \cos 2\theta$ and $\cos 4dt \sin 2\theta$. I'm sure you can somehow combine those (but I'm no expert at trigonometric functions).

Comment: @xiaohuamao Did you get this inequality while bashing a geometry problem?

Comment: @Asher2211 More or less, I originally had the 2D plane $r(\cos{\theta},\sin{\theta})$.

Comment: @xiaohuamao: You should explain why you think the inequality actually holds. Describing the geometric problem behind it might help, or showing the results of numerical or graphical simulations, etc. Otherwise, the possibility that the result might not actually be true (or might accidentally be mis-stated) could make some people less-than-enthusiastic about spending time on it. (Be sure to add any context or clarifications to the question itself, as comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue Thanks. Edited.